# Generate route with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, proxy

I used an action in a controller to generate routes from web addresses.

```
url_proxy:
    path:   /proxy
    defaults: { _controller: "PublicartelAppBundle:PlayContent:proxy" }
```

In my controller I used the generator of symfony routes, to do something like this:

```
public function proxyAction(Request $request){
    $url = $request->query->get('url');
    $generateUrl = $this->get('router')->generate('url_proxy', array('url' => $url));
    return new Response(file_get_contents($generateUrl));
}
```

Then, to prove I did:

**http://sgc.lo/public/proxy?url=http://www.google.com**

But that generates an error:

**Warning: file_get_contents (/public/proxy?url=http%3A//www.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

I think it's because the path is generated: **/public/proxy?url=http%3A//www.google.com** and should be

**sgc.lo/public/proxy?url=http%3A//www.google.com**

As I can include the prefix 'sgc.lo' in the route to generate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly ask for an absolute URL.

```
$this->get('router')
  ->generate('url_proxy', array('url' => $url), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Comment: For some reason, the url enters a loop and not finish loading. I must add my absolute path somewhere?

Comment: If you're running from the command line you'll need to add your domain explicitly.

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. I'm trying from the browser by entering the path to which is assigned the action in the controller.

Comment: You are hitting a loop because you are requesting your own route in the action (so route calls action, that they get file contents from route which calls action...). Your should change your response to `new Response(file_get_contents($url))` so that it gets the contents from the provided URL rather than your own.